# Inconsistency between in (mem) and out (dev,sql,etc) of process Transactor in Datomic:

Tags: clojure, datomic

I've discovered an inconsistency between the way `db.type/instant` values are handled in the in (mem) and out (dev,sql...) of process transactor.

When using the in process mem transactor the underlying type of a `db.type/instant` value is preserved when transacting and retrieving. For example, (type-printer uri) below shows that a transacted `java.util.TimeStamp` is retrieved as a `java.sql.TimeStamp`. However in the out of process transactors it is retrieved as a `java.util.Date`.

In most cases this inconsistency does not cause problems, however when dealing with bad Date implementations it can cause all sorts of problems. In my case the fact that `java.sql.TimeStamp` does not have a symmetric equals method, meant that a bug in my code only appeared when I ran it in an out of process transactor...

Obviously Datomic does not have any control over external implementations of `java.util.Date`, so I think the 'Date sanitisation' approach of the out of process transactors is correct.

Really all I want is a sanity check before I raise it as an issue with the Datomic guys so if someone could take a look and see if you agree it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Matt.

```
(require '[datomic.api :as d])

(import '(java.sql Timestamp)) 

(defn type-printer [uri] 

  "Prints the type of a transacted java.sql.TimeStamp when retrieved from the   databse" 
  (d/create-database uri) 
  (let [ts-att-schema {:db/id                 (d/tempid :db.part/db) 
                       :db/ident              :entity/ts 
                       :db/valueType          :db.type/instant 
                       :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one 
                       :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db} 
        ts (Timestamp. 1000000000000) 
        entity {:db/id     (d/tempid :db.part/user) 
                :entity/ts ts} 
        conn (d/connect uri)] 

    ;transact schema and then entity with associated TimeStamp value 
    @(d/transact conn [ts-att-schema]) 
    @(d/transact conn [entity]) 

    (let [type (->> (d/db conn) 
                    (d/q '[:find ?ts :where[?e :entity/ts ?ts]]) 
                    (first) 
                    (first) 
                    (type) 
                    )] 
      (println "java.sql.TimeStamp is retrived as type" type)))) 



;TimeStamp type is preserved when being transacted and then retrieved 
(type-printer "datomic:mem://test-db") 

;TimeStamp is sanitised in the database and retrieved as a java.util.Date.  This case obviously relies on a 
;dev transactor running on localhost:4334. Have only verified for dev and sql  transactors.
(type-printer "datomic:dev://localhost:4334/test-db")
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: A sanity check before I raise it as an issue with the Datomic guys. Just want to make sure I haven't missed anything.